Apply Pinch to Zoom with Drawing Features in Flutter
Now I am making a simple drawing app using flutter and I am using gestureDetector widget to detect user finger to get positions then pass it to custompaint widget's painter , the problem now is I want to apply zoom in and out too , but I noticed that I can't use OnScale functions with the OnPan ones so how to solve that ?
this my original code :
  Sketch sketch = Sketch(points: []);
  final GlobalKey _repaintBoundaryKey = GlobalKey();
  Hiveservices hive = Hiveservices();
  double _sacle = 1.0;
  double _pScale = 1.0;

 
 GestureDetector(
         
          onPanStart: (details) {
            Offset offset = details.localPosition;
            setState(() {
              sketch.points.add(offset);
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            Offset offset = details.localPosition;
            setState(() {
              sketch.points.add(offset);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            setState(() {
              context.read<UndoRedoCubit>().addToList(sketch);
              // list.add(sketch);
              sketch = Sketch(
                points: [],
                strokeColor: sketch.strokeColor,
                isEraser: sketch.isEraser,
                strokeSize:
                    sketch.isEraser ? sketch.estrokeSize : sketch.strokeSize,
                brushmode: sketch.brushmode,
              );
            });
          },
          child: BlocBuilder<UndoRedoCubit, UndoRedoState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
            return RepaintBoundary(
              key: _repaintBoundaryKey,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  widget.impath != null
                      ? Image.asset(
                          widget.impath!,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: double.infinity,
                        )
                      : widget.history != null
                          ? Image.memory(
                              widget.history!,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: double.infinity,
                            )
                          : Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: double.infinity,
                            ),
                  CustomPaint(
                    painter: PaintCanvas(
                      sketches: state.undoList + [sketch],
                    ),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
     

and I tried to use two separate gesture detectors one for zoom and one for drawing also didn't work like that

  double _scale = 1.0;
  double _pScale = 1.0;
  bool _isScaling = false;
 GestureDetector(
          onScaleStart: _handleScaleStart,
          onScaleUpdate: _handleScale,
          onScaleEnd: (details) {
            setState(() {
              _isScaling = false;
            });
          },
          child: GestureDetector(
          
            onPanStart: _isScaling
                ? null
                : (details) {
                    // Only handle pan if not scaling
                    Offset offset = details.localPosition;
                    setState(() {
                      sketch.points.add(offset);
                    });
                  },
            onPanUpdate: _isScaling
                ? null
                : (details) {
                    // Only handle pan if not scaling
                    Offset offset = details.localPosition;
                    setState(() {
                      sketch.points.add(offset);
                    });
                  },
            onPanEnd: (details) {
              setState(() {
                context.read<UndoRedoCubit>().addToList(sketch);
                // list.add(sketch);
                sketch = Sketch(
                  points: [],
                  strokeColor: sketch.strokeColor,
                  isEraser: sketch.isEraser,
                  strokeSize:
                      sketch.isEraser ? sketch.estrokeSize : sketch.strokeSize,
                  brushmode: sketch.brushmode,
                );
              });
            },
            child: BlocBuilder<UndoRedoCubit, UndoRedoState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
              return RepaintBoundary(
                key: _repaintBoundaryKey,
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.diagonal3(Vector3(_scale, _scale, _scale)),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      widget.impath != null
                          ? Image.asset(
                              widget.impath!,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: double.infinity,
                            )
                          : widget.history != null
                              ? Image.memory(
                                  widget.history!,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  height: double.infinity,
                                )
                              : Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  height: double.infinity,
                                ),
                      CustomPaint(
                        painter: PaintCanvas(
                          sketches: state.undoList + [sketch],
                        ),
                        child: Container(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
     

also I tried the zoomWidget package and interactiveviewer widget they didn't work as well
so what I should do ?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
